# Client invoke SignalR hub routine in web farm. No affinity

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

Details:

- 2 IIS servers with a load balancer.
- WEB Sockets configured on server(win2012 r2).
- Both Servers have the same site running SignalR
- Client is a windows form app on win7. Transport = serverSentEvents
- A backplane is configured using Redis
- The Hub sends a message to a specific client by connectionid
- I Need the client to RESPOND to the SAME server. Some type of affinity.
- I have the call to the client working.
- I have the RESPONSE call to the hub working (see code below)
- Problem: The RESPONSE goes to to any server in the web farm, not the same one that sent the original message

How do I ensure the client RESPONDS to the same server in the web farm?

Server Routine in Hub

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void RoutineOnMyHub(object myObject)
    {
        //do work
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
_Hub.Invoke("RoutineOnMyHub", myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into scaleout with SignalR:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

You can use a backplane to connect all the servers in your web farm to a single message bus.

Comment: Yes, per the details there is a backplane configured.